# Slice array of structs using column values

Tags: apache-spark

I want to use Spark slice function with start and length defined as `Column`(s).

`def slice(x: Column, start: Int, length: Int): Column`

`x` looks like this:

```
`|-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b : double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- e: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- g: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- h: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- i: double (nullable = true)
...
`
```

any idea on how to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: you need it for array column or just a string column?

Comment: array column (my column was created with `struct("a","b","c")  as "agg1" `

Comment: "a", "b" and "c" are arrays?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the built-in DataFrame DSL function `slice` for this (as it needs constant slice bounds), you can use an UDF for that. If `df` is your dataframe and you have a `from` und `until` column, then you can do:

```scala
val mySlice = udf(
  (data:Seq[Row], from:Int, until:Int) => data.slice(from,until),
  df.schema.fields.find(_.name=="x").get.dataType
)

df
  .select(mySlice($"x",$"from",$"until"))
  .show()
```

Alternatively, you can use the SQL-Expression in Spark SQL:

```
df
   .select(expr("slice(x,from,until)"))
   .show()
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1. what is `df.schema.fields.find(_.name=="x").get.dataType` (is there anything missing) , 2. Any idea for a DS (instead of DF)

Comment: @GuillaumeG this is a trick to get the schema of your array, it lets you return `Seq[Row]` from your UDF, so you don't need to map the struct to a Tuple. 2: With DS it's trivial, just use the slice method of the scala collection API

Comment: My `from` and `to` are stored as columns. Would you do something like this ? `expr("slice(x,from,length)"))`

Comment: Thanks for changing your comment. Can you fix the typo in the UDF and I will accept it as final

Comment: .@GuillaumeG I dont see a typo

Comment: The comma at the end of `data.slice(from,until),` looks suspicious. Also, `df` in your udf is not defined ? Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: @GuillaumeG Its correct as it is, `df` is the original dataframe as I explained in the answer.